# How to implement the "tap-hold and pull down to show the entire message" in GCM notifications in Android

Tags: android

I am writing some Android code to handle GCM notifications. I have seen in most of the apps, that when the notification comes, it shows up in the home screen as a brief text, but when we hold on it, and pull it down, it shows the rest of the message as well. I want to implement that in my code. My code goes something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(bm)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.some_pic)
                    .setContentTitle("Some Title")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

but it still doesn't work. What more do I need to add to it, in order for it to not just show a one-line text with a "..." at the end, but show the entire message on pulling the notification down?

Comment: This code should already allow the notification expand if contentText doesn't fit on one line. Remember expandable notifications were introduced in Android 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think expendable view for notification will help you to show your entire message in expendable mode.
you can you use expendable view like this.

```
  RemoteViews expandedView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
   R.layout.notification_expendable_view);
 expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_expendable_text,
 your entire message);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.bulid();
notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =  
(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(101, notification);
```

And a layout file in your layout folder name with notification_expendable_view.

notification_expendable_view.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_expendable_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
  </LinerLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any alternate for the line `notification.bigContentView = expandedView;` so that it works for API levels not only from 16 onwards, but also for 14 and 15 as well?

Comment: "Big views were introduced in Android 4.1, and they're not supported on older devices."

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html

Comment: So is there anything that I can do as a workaround for this, for API versions 14 or 15?

Comment: @SanjibanBairagya actually not, there is no option to use this in below than api 16.